# How can I fix a segmentation fault on C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Im trying to build this for the amd64arch and it keeps giving me segmentation fault:

```
    #include "client.h"

      namespace {

    class SimpleClientImpl : public SimpleClient {
    private:
      int progress_counter_;

    public:
      SimpleClientImpl() : progress_counter_(0) {}

      int GetProgress() const;
      char* CutPrefix(char* data);
    };

    int SimpleClientImpl::GetProgress() const {
      return progress_counter_;
    }

    char* SimpleClientImpl::CutPrefix(char* data) {
      progress_counter_++;
      return data + *reinterpret_cast<size_t*>(data) + sizeof(size_t);
    }

    }  // namespace

    std::shared_ptr<SimpleClient> CreateSimpleClient() {
      return std::shared_ptr<SimpleClient>(new SimpleClientImpl);
    }
```

In the client.h I got:

```
    #ifndef TEST_CLIENT_H_
    #define TEST_CLIENT_H_

    #include <memory>

    class SimpleClient {
    public:
      virtual int GetProgress() const = 0;
      virtual char* CutPrefix(char* data) = 0;
      virtual ~SimpleClient() {}
    };

    std::shared_ptr<SimpleClient> CreateSimpleClient();

    #endif
```

Any Idea of how can i fix this? I'm not sure why would it give me a segmentation fault, i've tryed runnin it as admin, but I dont really get where is the problem.

Comment: What did you see when you ran it through a debugger?

Comment: This `reinterpret_cast` smells.

Comment: It's difficult to say without a complete program, but that pointer arithmetic looks fishy (and a wee bit undefined). What's its purpose and what is your input?

Comment: Since the program is broken, we cannot determine what it is supposed to do by reading it. _Because it does not do that thing._ Explain your goal.

Comment: "i've tryed runnin it as admin" - that's the last thing you want to try if your program has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 char* CutPrefix(char* data);
```

You ***may*** never allocate memory for that pointer on string (Either with new or the c malloc) ;

My guess is that you miswrote this line :

```
return data + *reinterpret_cast<size_t*>(data) + sizeof(size_t);
```

And that you should either work with `strings`, or do your allocation correctly beforehands if you really want to keep working with char* in cpp.

Comment: _"You never allocate memory for that pointer on string"_ How do you know?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit by elemination, it's either a non-allocation, or a miscalculated one Lrio'.

Comment: Then why are you strictly asserting that it _must_ be just one of those things? There are all sorts of reasons you could have an invalid pointer, and the problem might not even be an invalid pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Although you haven't shown calling code, it is presumably creating a `SimpleClientImpl` and passing (the address of) some character buffer to the `CutPrefix()` member function.   Possibly repeatedly.

Check the data that is being supplied to `CutPrefix()`.   Either it is not encoded in the form you assume (a length, followed by that number of characters) or the caller is walking past the end of the supplied buffer.   Possibly both.

In either case, the caller will exhibit undefined behaviour if it uses the pointer returned.

Since you haven't provided the calling code, however, it is not possible to advise on how to fix the problem.